# State_dict error for testing a model that is trained by loading checkpoints

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I trained a model using PyTorch and I stored the weights in which it had the minimum validation loss during training. Also, I stored the optimizer weights on that time.  So, I trained my model for the second time by loading the weights that I stored from the first time. I wanted to test my model and generate the outputs of my model.
But, unfortunately, I faced with such an error:

[image]

When I wanted to load the weights for the second_time training I used the following scripts:

```
    model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids = [0,1],output_device= [0,1])
    
    model = model.to(dev)

    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path_to_the_saved_model's_weights, map_location=dev))
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=2e-7)

    
    # loading optimizer
    optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load(path to the saved optimizer's weights))
```

I only changed learning rate value during the second_time training and when I want to test the model and generating the output of the model by loading the new weights I see such an error. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: please do not post screen shots of logs/stack traces - copy-paste the text to your post and format it accordingly.

Comment: try loading the state_dict **before** wrapping the model with `DataParallel`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I stored the optimizer weights on that time [...] I only changed learning rate

This is not possible in the way you are describing it (cf. to the comments in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/4044)). If you change the optimizer *(e.g. editing the learning rate)*, you can't load the previous state of the optimizer as both are incompatible. Using `optimizer.load_state_dict(...)` the way you did won't work therefore.

There are two solutions for that issue:

**1.** You can save the whole optimizer object itself (including the configuration and state with which you left of):

```
# Save optimizer
torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), "optimizer.pt")

# Load optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=2e-7)
optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load("optimizer.pt"))
```

*Or more simple with `torch.save(optimizer, "optimizer.pt")` for saving and loading with `optimizer = torch.load("optimizer.pt")`.*

With this approach you **won't be able** to adjust your optimizer *(e.g. adjusting the learning rate)*. Generally, this is the best way - as you should start with a fresh optimizer if you're changing fundamental things (such as the learning rate).

If however, you decide that you specifically want to continue on your current learning state / weights with a newly configured optimizer - you may use the following option:

**2.** You can just save the weights themselves (without the optimizer's state - as you will change the optimizer configuration anyway) and then load the weights with a newly created optimizer with your desired learning rate:

```
# Load the weights of the model 
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path_weights, map_location=dev))

# Create a new optimizer with new configs
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=2e-7)
```